# Expand RDD and assign contiguous IDs to the new elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wish to disambiguate the `Foo`. Some of them need to be split into separate instances. Each needs a unique, contiguous Id.

```
val maxId: Long = foos.map(_.id).max()

foos.flatMap { foo =>
  if (foo.bar) List(foo, foo.copy(id = ???, ...))
  else List(foo)
}
```

In plain Scala, I'd use a foldLeft. With Spark, the best I can think of is to flatMap to `(Foo, Option[Long])`, filter by `_._2.isEmpty`, zipWithIndex and join.  Is there a smarter way?

e.g. given

```
case class Foo(id: Long) {
  val bar: Boolean = id % 2 == 1
}
```

This input

```
RDD( Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3) )
```

should become

```
RDD( Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4), Foo(5) )
```

because `Foo(1)` and `Foo(3)` expanded and took on the next available ids (4 & 5).

Comment: Maybe others can understand what your problem is but I can't figure it out. In general, all of the typical operations (in particular, monad operations) that you're used to on regular Scala collections can be used on RDDs.

Comment: Ah, OK. I've put a succinct example in the question.

Comment: @Synesso is order of collection  elements is important?

Comment: @Odomontois not important

Answer (score 1):

In any distributed system identifires that can be produced indepedently of each other outperform sequential generators.

So nice way is `.copy( id = randomLong )`, best way is `.copy( id = UUID.randomUUID() )`

But question is specific about **contiguous** ids. My proposal for that case is

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

abstract class UpdateIDS[T: ClassTag, Id: Numeric : ClassTag] extends Serializable {
  def getId(elem: T): Id
  def setId(elem: T, id: Id): T
  def shouldChange(elem: T): Boolean
  val Id = implicitly[Numeric[Id]]

  def apply(xs: RDD[T]): RDD[T] = {
    val next = xs.map(getId).max + Id.one
    val counts: Seq[(Int, Int)] = xs.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (idx, elems) =>
      Iterator.single(idx, elems.count(shouldChange))
    }.collect.view
    val starts = counts.map(_._2).map(Id.fromInt).scanLeft(next)(_ + _)
    val startMapLocal = counts.zip(starts).map { case ((idx, _), start) => (idx, start) }.toMap
    val startMap = xs.context.broadcast(startMapLocal)

    xs.mapPartitionsWithIndex { case (idx, elems) =>
      elems.scanLeft((List.empty[T], startMap.value(idx))) { (pair, elem) =>
        pair match {
          case (_, counter) if shouldChange(elem) => (List(elem, setId(elem, counter)), counter + Id.one)
          case (_, counter) => (List(elem), counter)
        }
      }.flatMap { _._1 }
    }
  }
}
```

with that you can easily define

```
object fooUpdateId extends UpdateIDS[Foo, Int] {
  def getId(foo: Foo) = foo.id
  def setId(foo: Foo, id: Int) = foo.copy(id = id)
  def shouldChange(foo: Foo) = foo.id % 2 == 1
}
```

and then run

```
val foosUpdated = fooUpdateId(foos)
```

**important note** here that order of generated collection is altered for more performant solution. If you'll need order in not-so-big RDDs you can use then `sortBy`.

also note that implementation of `UpdadeIDs` could be somewhat simplier using `mapAccumL` and `Lens` from scalaz, but I choose to avoid external libraries.

Comment: I assume then that zipWithIndex is local to the partition, right? 

So the gist here is to count the number to be altered per partition and assign start indices, broadcast this to the cluster and then each partition uses it's own start index to assign unique, contiguous indices.

I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Synesso exactly, if by `zipWithIndex` you mean `mapPartitionsWithIndex`